# web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: python-3.x, solidity

while connecting smart contract function using python for method owner_only functions.while transacting a smart contract for voting using python ,I am getting this error.can any one please help me

python code

web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0]
h=contract.functions.addCandidate(str(name),str(region)).transact()

web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(h)

error :
raise ContractLogicError(f'execution reverted: {response["error"]["message"]}')
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

solidity code

```
modifier ownerOnly() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function Election(string _name) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    electionName = _name;
}

function addCandidate(string name,string region) ownerOnly public {
    candidates.push(Candidate(name, 0,region));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.